# PowerPC macs and 12.04 LTS Application Support

Tags: 12.04, mac, powerpc

So, I have an older computer sitting in the closet, a PowerMac G5 tower. A great machine, a whole lot better than my Dell that I'm currently using, so my question is, with a PowerPC processor would the application support here on Ubuntu work with out the issues of OSX's terrible drop in application support? Would say, Super Meat Boy from the software center work? Or is all that computer good for is web browsing?

In other words, can a PowerPC G5 Processor work with Ubuntu applications, or is it doomed to be without support from all providers?

Answer (score 1):

For this machine, I would recommend Lubuntu. Ubuntu with a lighter desktop environment. Here is the link: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/

This will run on your machine, faster, and cleaner then other versions of Ubuntu would. 
For aditional help with Lubuntu, visit http://www.lubuntu.net/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the age of the machine, I'd say it may not have enough RAM, or other resources to really perform well with Ubuntu 12.04, if you could get it running. The Humble Bundle games are also not likely available. Proprietary end-user applications are generally only available for x86 or x86_64 architectures on Linux. You could use an emulator to get it working on PowerPC possibly, but it would also almost certainly be unbearably slow and unplayable if you were to get it working.

Comment: It's a dual core 2.0 Ghz with 1 GB of RAM, which, compared with my Dell here Single Core 2.4 Ghz and 768 Mbs of RAM I'd been thinking it would run a little better.

Comment: It might run a little better, but probably not a whole lot better. The CPU speed isn't the problem there, but the RAM. It'll run, but you really need at least 2GB to get reasonably good performance out of it.